# Convert 2D object array C# to Javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I'm converting a 2D object array into javascript, but I'm having trouble with the JSON serializer.

My controller has this:

```
object[,] array = new object[,] {{"Name", "Donuts eaten"},
                                          {"Michael", 5},
                                          {"Elisa", 7},
                                          {"Robert", 3},
                                          {"John", 2},
                                          {"Jessica", 6},
                                          {"Aaron", 1},
                                          {"Margareth", 8}};
ViewBag.DataArray =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
```

My script uses:

```
var dataArray = '@ViewBag.DataArray';
```

However, when the script is run, I get this:

```
var dataArray = '[[&quot;Name&quot;,&quot;Donuts eaten&quot;],[&quot;Michael&quot;,5],[&quot;Elisa&quot;,7],[&quot;Robert&quot;,3],[&quot;John&quot;,2],[&quot;Jessica&quot;,6],[&quot;Aaron&quot;,1],[&quot;Margareth&quot;,8]]';
```

Any help or alternate methods would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you want your output to be?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `@` symbol, razor will do an HTML encode on the result of the expression followed by @. If you do not want the content to be encoded, use `Html.Raw` method.

```
var dataArray = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataArray)';
```

Now razor will produce the below output.

```
var dataArray = '[["Name","Donuts eaten"],["Michael",5],["Elisa",7],["Robert",3],
                                    ["John",2],["Jessica",6],["Aaron",1],["Margareth",8]]';
```